# Check if all other checkboxes are checked; working but I want something more

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

```
<script>$(function(){
  $('#admin_permission_check').on('change',function(){
     $('.admin_permission_check').prop('checked',$(this).prop('checked'));
  });
  $('.admin_permission_check').on('change',function(){
     $('#admin_permission_check').prop('checked',$('.admin_permission_check:checked').length ? true: false);
  });

});</script>
<input type=checkbox id='admin_permission_check' value="1" /> Select All
<input type=checkbox class='admin_permission_check' value="2" />
<input type=checkbox class='admin_permission_check' value="2" />
```

This is working fine and i am able to check all check boxes with class admin_permission_check when checkbox with id admin_permission_check is being checked.

But when i have unchecked any checkbox with class admin_permission_check then the checkbox with id admin_permission_check is not being unchecked automatically and what should i do to if all the checkboxes with class admin_permission_check are checked already on pageload then the checkbox with id admin_permission_check automatically gets checked.

I don't know about Javascript but searching helped me to achieve the code above which is working but not as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`:not()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) to see if one of the checkboxes is not checked and after this you can adjust the checked property of the first one with id. The same function can be called on [document ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) to set the checked attribute of "Select All" checkbox if other checkboxes are checked. See the snippet below (I've put the initialization into setCheckBoxUpHandlers method to allow passing the id/class name for some different test cases).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  setCheckBoxUpHandlers('admin_permission_check');
  setCheckBoxUpHandlers('admin_permission_check1');
  setCheckBoxUpHandlers('admin_permission_check2');
});


function setCheckBoxUpHandlers(name){
  $('#' + name).on('change',function(){
    $('.' + name).prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
  });

  function checkIfAllAreChecked(){
    $('#'+ name).prop('checked', $('.' + name + ':not(:checked)').length ? false: true);
  }

  checkIfAllAreChecked();

  $('.' + name).on('change',function(){
    checkIfAllAreChecked();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=checkbox id='admin_permission_check' value="1" /> Select All
<input type=checkbox class='admin_permission_check' value="2" />
<input type=checkbox class='admin_permission_check' value="2" />

<br/>
<span>-------------------------------------------------------------------</span>
<br/>

<input type=checkbox id='admin_permission_check1' value="3" /> Select All
<input type=checkbox class='admin_permission_check1' value="4" />
<input type=checkbox class='admin_permission_check1' value="4" checked/>
<input type=checkbox class='admin_permission_check1' value="4" />

<br/>
<span>-------------------------------------------------------------------</span>
<br/>

<input type=checkbox id='admin_permission_check2' value="5" /> Select All
<input type=checkbox class='admin_permission_check2' value="6" checked/>
<input type=checkbox class='admin_permission_check2' value="6" checked/>
```